# Cannot get Synergy to start with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, boot, init.d

I've tried multiple ways to get it to work,

https://learn.adafruit.com/synergy-on-raspberry-pi/setup-synergy-client-autostart

https://www.rootusers.com/compiling-synergy-from-source-on-the-raspberry-pi/

And that method adding the command to rc.local.

Nothing works unless I call them manually...

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I believe that synergy uses x windows and hence can't be invoked using `rc.local` as by the time `rc.local` executes, x-windows is not up. You can try adding it to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` instead of what is shown in that link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Isn't that effecitevely the asme as the first link?

Comment: Since you're able to run it manually, there is nothing wrong in compilation or otherwise. I think program is not being called from start up script properly, most probably because newer version of Raspbian calls autostart from `LXDE-pi` instead of normal `LXDE` startup, not sure why this change in newer versions, may be someone experienced or someone having deeper knowledge of Raspbian can shed some light on this.

Comment: @dastaan I think you're right if you want to add that as an answer quick.

Comment: @goldilocks Added. :)

Comment: No luck so far. Best alternative is manually starting it with SSH from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo nano ~/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

Add path to the synergy startup script like this.

```
@sh /home/pi/synergy
```

With synergy containing ( for me )

```
#!/bin/shell
killall synergyc
/home/pi/Downloads/synergy-1.4.18-Source/bin/synergyc --name Pi 192.168.123.181
```

[Confirmed working on Jessie.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmjXG.jpg)

Edit as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since synergy uses x-windows and hence can't be invoked using `rc.local` as by the time `rc.local` executes, x-windows is not up and running. You can try adding it to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` as per below steps:

1. `sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsesssion/LXDE-pi/autostart`
2. Add : `@/path/to/your/script.sh` at the end.
3. Ctrl + x --> `y` to save changes.
4. `sudo reboot` to see if it works.

As per links in question, I think the method described in it is not working because newer versions of Raspbian calls autostart from `LXDE-pi` instead of normal `LXDE` startup, not sure why this change in newer versions, may be someone experienced or someone having deeper knowledge of Raspbian can shed some light on this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't get it to work. https://i.imgur.com/ScBnoCs.png

Comment: @Nos Try `@/full/path/to/synergyc --name pi 192.168.123.181`. Make sure file rights are as per required.

Comment: Like this? https://i.imgur.com/Epk80d7.png

Comment: @Nos Use absolute path like this : `@/home/pi/Downloads/Synergy/bin/synergyc --name pi 192.168.123.181`  This should ideally work.

Comment: Dang, that didn't work. Also says no such file or directory if I manually enter it in the terminal.

Comment: By any change, does synergy need `sudo` ? If yes, you will have to use `@sudo /home/...`  First make sure, it runs by manually executing `/home/pi/Downloads/Synergy/bin/synergyc --name pi 192.168.123.181`, once it works, I don't think autostart would have any problem executing it.

Comment: Synergy does not require sudo. It does not run by manually executing your path. It does in with the 2 I posted.

Comment: @Nos Just wondering if you were able to find out the solution ? I tried compiling synergy on my Rpi but synergyc starts with `uname -a` output and doesn't show anything on GUI. Not sure how it is supposed to behave.

Comment: I'm afraid not, so far. It either tells you the status of the program, like when you move the mouse from the server to the client, with --no-daemon, and just runs in the background with no arg, but it'll echo its version and location and such.

Comment: This is how it looks like when it's running in the background.
http://i.imgur.com/5dJb1Ow.png

Comment: Success, with the efforts of your and [JimmyN's](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=124966&p=839326#p839326) I finally got it working as described in the answer. Thanks dastaan.